# showing that there are outliers in a matplotlib plot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, scatter-plot, outliers

Assume there is a scatter plot with axis between 0 to 2 in both x and y. There are points outside this range which are not necessary to be shown in the plot.
Is there a built in module in matplotlib that can be used to show arrows(or any similar symbol) at the edges of the axes showing that there are points outside the plot range?

Answer (score 0):

There's an annotate method that you can use. [Here's a link with examples](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html).

You can also add your own arrows and text objects.

Comment: thanks @RJT but this is not what I was looking for with this post. I was wondering if there was a built in method within matplotlib itself, which automatically identifies that there are outliers to the plot range and shows arrows(could be on arrow per point or a collective) at the edges of the plot showing their presence. I guess its a handy tool that the module should have?